# VSCode adds random percentage

Tags: shell, visual-studio-code, terminal, zsh

Everytime I use the terminal to print out a string or any kind of character, it automatically prints an "%" at the end of each line. This happens everytime I try to print something from C++ or php, havent tried other languages yet. I think it might be something with vscode, and have no idea how it came or how to fix it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int test = 2;

int main()
{
    if(test < 9999){
        test = 1;
    }

    cout << test;
}
```

Output:

```
musti@my-mbp clus % g++ main.cpp -o tests && ./tests
1%
```

Also changing the cout from `cout << test;` to `cout << test << endl;` Removes the % from the output.

Comment: it is the prompt of the terminal, copy-paste the terminal content (no image)

Comment: Here is an example. 2% It supposed to only show 2, but for some reason adds the "%

Comment: show complete terminal output and your C++ code

Comment: I have edited my post

Comment: what is the `%` in front of `g++`, it is the same `%`

Comment: don't use `using namespace std;`, always completely specify namespace of variables: `std::cout` `std::endl`

Comment: don't name your source or output anything like `test`: it will give you trouble sometime

Comment: I don't know why the % is there, it seems to be in the terminal prompt name, I do not know if it's always been there. It may be the cause to it.

Comment: Is your program the only thing sending characters to the screen, or might the shell also be printing stuff

Comment: Writing a simple echo "test" in shell does not add the %. But if I do the same in c++ or php and run the code from the terminal (also outside of vscode) it adds the %

Comment: why would you compare a shell `echo` statement with a C++ program? `echo` has nothing to do with VSC. Compile and run outside VSC and see what happens. What happens if you `cout` 2 things?

Comment: Same thing happens if I compile and run it outside of vscode, and if I cout 2 things

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using zsh? A line without `endl` is considered a "partial line", so zsh shows a color-inverted `%` then goes to the next line.

> When a partial line is preserved, by default you will see an inverse+bold character at the end of the partial line: a ‘%’ for a normal user or a ‘#’ for root. If set, the shell parameter PROMPT_EOL_MARK can be used to customize how the end of partial lines are shown.

More information is available in their [docs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#Prompting).